# Join List of words to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Table "List" and table "Content". I want to store 6 types of lists. These lists are black,white and grey lists and each of these list contain a few words. Whenever someone notices  a new word that should be in one of the lists, then new word should be simply added to the database.
The image below shows you the tables that I use.
[image]

I want to refer or join a certain list for instance a list with name: "Blacklist" that has an ListID= 1 with the correct set of blacklistwords, that could have a ContentID=1.

The content is a list of words, but I am clueless as for how I should join the correct list of words(content) to a listID. I don't know how to query this.

The part that is troubeling me is that it is a list of words. So a ContentID =1 has for example the words"Login","Password", "Credential" etc. How do I query it to ListID=1 with the name"BlackList"? And do the same for the other lists?

I think it should look like this.

```
SELECT ID
FROM List
LEFT JOIN Content
    ON LIST.ID = ContenID AND CONTENT.ISDEFAULT = 1
WHERE ListID = 1
```

This only joins the two ID with each other. How do I join the correct list of words with the correct list? Maybe I am totally missing the point with the query above?

Question: How do I join a set or list of words to a list with a name and ListID?

Comment: Please specify the schema also. There should be a list id field in Content table to make an association with List table (Other than the actual primary key of Content table)

Comment: @Thanga, Sorry for the stupid question but, at school they thought me that  if I have a relationship that is 1 on 1 it should not have an association? Is this wrong or is my association wrong?

Comment: "one to (which) one" is implemented by this kind of foreign key association

Comment: @Thanga I think I changed it the right way? I put the ListID in the content table. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. this is what i meant

Comment: @Thanga Ok thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I think ListID was missing in Content table, because the foreign key in Content that matches ListID is actually ContentID (at least, that's what it seems looking at the SQL join clause). What I don't get from there, where does the field IsDefault come from? What's the result you get from running that query, and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Once you change this schema, the below query will work

```
SELECT ListID,ContentID,Words
FROM List
LEFT JOIN Content
ON List.ListID = Content.ListID
WHERE List.ListID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have considered the schema from the diagrams. Please execute the below query:

```
SELECT 
    L.Name AS 'ListName',
    C.Words 
FROM List L
INNER JOIN Content C ON C.ListID = L.ListID
WHERE 
    C.Words IN ('Login','Password','Credential')
```